# Deleted ldf files, Sharepoint database schema lost

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, content-database, sql-server-2012

After deleting manually ldf files related to the share point databases, it's impossible to connect to SharePoint sites. It shows: "Cannot connect to the configuration database"

It is not related to restarting SQL and Sharepoint services, the services run normally, but looking at the databases in SQL Server managent Studio , their schemas have been destroyed - there is no structure in them, they show as mere folders. They're basically either empty or corrupted. There is no cross symbol next to it to open it, and when i right click -> Reports, it prompts an error ''this property may not exist for this object, or may not be retrievable due to insufficient access rights".

From the logs:

```
Login failed for user 'DS\SharepointService'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database

SQL Database 'SharePoint_Config' on SQL Server instance 'spn' not found. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.

Cannot open database "SharePoint_Config" requested by the login. The login failed.
```

I have no idea where to search next, as this installation was not done by me in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

So, why were the ldf files deleted? Those are the SQL log files, and by "log", they are a core piece of SQL functionality, they're not just there for historical messages.

You'll need to restore your farm. The specific steps will vary, based on how the farm was backed up, but [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428314.aspx#proc3) are the basic instructions to restore a farm.

Answer (score 0):

A database need both MDF (Data files) & LDF ( Logs File) files, LDF are the transaction log files of db.

Mostly people trying to touch the LDF files because of their size, if thats the issue then you can simply shrink the Logs file rather than delete them.

Now, as you deleted the LDF file..you have to perform a database backup (if multiple dbs affected then you have to restore every db).

For future follow these instruction for shrinking.

- Right click WSS_Content and choose Tasks -> Backup
- Select backtup type "Transaction log", select destination backup file and click Ok.
- After backing up the DB, right click WSS_Content and choose Tasks -> Shrink -> Files
- Select the type log and shrink action (eg release unused space)

https://serverfault.com/questions/56643/can-i-delete-a-large-ldf-file-in-sharepoint